# click to add div: am I "doing it wrong"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

*(I'm a refugee from the Flex/Actionscript world and am trying to make the switch to html5/css3/JS. If this question is a duplicate or too dumb, let me know and I will delete it)*

**The Exercise:** make an "app" with a "clickable" image background which creates new elements on a click event (and not using `canvas`);

I've got a functioning result – it just adds an empty colored `div` on click – but it seems like I am working way too hard – concatenating and converting to strings, reaching into the css style, etc. I'm also not clear how I would go about:

- adding some Javascript behaviors to the newly created elements (so that it would be possible, for example, to drag these elements). I tried adding an eventListener to the newly created element but the `blockClicked` function never gets called;
- trapping clicks on newly created elements so they don't pass through to the background, causing new items to get stacked on top of each other
- creating an instance of something more complex than an empty `div` - like an html "component" – with an image, label, etc. without having to build an html string in JS.

Is there a better or cleaner way to do this sort of thing? I've been looking at various JS frameworks but didn't want to jump into something abstract before I understood some of the basics (and the problems these frameworks solve).

---

JS

```
"use strict";

var counter = 0;
var levelImg;
var eventContainer;

function setupBackground() {
    eventContainer = document.getElementById("event-container");
    levelImg = document.getElementById("levelImage");
    levelImg.addEventListener("click", addEventItem);
};

 function blockClicked(event){
    console.log("blockClicked");
}

function addEventItem(event) {
    console.log("create one");
    var rectArray = levelImg.getClientRects();
    var rect =  rectArray[0];
    var w = 40;
    var h = 80;
    // define x/y relative to edge of background image
    // and offset position so div appears centered at mouse click
    var xPos = (event.pageX - rect.left) - (w/2);
    var yPos = (event.pageY - rect.top) -(h/2);

    var divTmp = document.createElement("div");
    divTmp.className = "levelEvent";
    divTmp.id = "event" + counter++;
    divTmp.addEventListener("click", blockClicked, false);
    divTmp.style.width = w + 'px';
    divTmp.style.height = h + 'px';
    divTmp.style.left = xPos + 'px';
    divTmp.style.top = yPos + 'px';

    eventContainer.appendChild(divTmp);
}
```

---

CSS

```
.levelEvent {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: palegreen;
    display:block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 120;
    max-height: 120;
}

#content-container{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#event-container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 4px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

---

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>B</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">


</head>

<body onload="setupBackground()">
    <script src="js/clickToAdd.js"></script>
    <div id="content-container">
        <img id="levelImage" src="images/image3.png" width="100%" />

        <div id="event-container">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely not doing it wrong, although I found 2 issues:

- `max-width: 120` is ignored because `px` is missing
- I bet that the following part of your code is intended to work differently. I think, when you scroll down, the green rectangles should still appear under the cursor when clicking: (I tried it out in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy9fdbhg/))

  ```
  var xPos = event.pageX - rect.left;
  var yPos = event.pageY - rect.top;
  ```

  My suggestion:

  ```
  var xPos = event.pageX;
  var yPos = event.pageY;
  ```